# Font size class get reset back to default

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, uilabel, size-classes

I have a game made with Unity, and combined it with iOS (provided as library) to provide some native features.

I use this [UnityNativePrototype](https://github.com/haxpor/UnityNativePrototype) which I forked from original creator [samizzo](https://github.com/samizzo). It works fine, but right after I tested it with iPad 2. Things seem to be not right.

A little bit of concept of integration between iOS and Unity is this. I have 3 projects

1. iOS Library (storyboard, native code, etc)
2. iOS Test app (to consume iOS library and quickly test things out)
3. Unity project (generated XCode project of Unity game)

Whenever I want to test all things together, I combine 1. and 3. together. Only 2. I use for quick testing because integrating a final app between Unity and iOS requires time.

I use size class to set font size for `UILabel`in Storyboard. I tested it with 2. and it works fine. But **problem** occurs whenever I test it with integrated app, `UILabel` sets back to use default font size I have set with size class Any:Any. It suddenly changes after I touch on the view. I even applied work around by sub-classing `UILabel` then override `setFont` method to force setting a correct font size. It works but has a problem with layout later on in which no matter I call `layoutIfNeeded` on the view, it doesn't look like.

The following is debug log I print it out to see if there's a call to set new font to `UILabel`. And it did...

```
2015-09-24 08:11:09.501 ProductName[1475:611412] Some changes going on here...<UICTFont: 0x19177700> font-family: ".SFUIDisplay-Regular"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 24.00pt
2015-09-24 08:11:36.896 ProductName[1475:611412] Some changes going on here...<UICTFont: 0x156754a0> font-family: ".SFUIText-Regular"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 17.00pt
```

Above, firstly it normally sets font & font-size according to what I've set in Storyboard. But then it is called to set again. This time back to normal which I don't want.

The following is call stack. Please note that it seems so normal that the call is not initiated from Unity native support classes, or even my own project.

```
2015-09-24 09:59:58.265 ProductName[1605:635812] Stracktrace: (
    0   ProductName                         0x00bee2a3 -[UILabelFix setFont:] + 182
    1   Foundation                          0x24fb3e1b <redacted> + 226
    2   UIKit                               0x286559e7 <redacted> + 174
    3   Foundation                          0x24fc62e3 <redacted> + 310
    4   UIKit                               0x287776d7 <redacted> + 322
    5   UIKit                               0x28776d11 <redacted> + 192
    6   UIKit                               0x28648edd <redacted> + 80
    7   UIKit                               0x28648f9f <redacted> + 134
    8   UIKit                               0x28649211 <redacted> + 44
    9   UIKit                               0x28b32f79 <redacted> + 144
    10  UIKit                               0x286491cd <redacted> + 320
    11  UIKit                               0x28359429 <redacted> + 660
    12  QuartzCore                          0x27c2aad1 <redacted> + 128
    13  QuartzCore                          0x27c261cd <redacted> + 348
    14  QuartzCore                          0x27c26061 <redacted> + 16
    15  QuartzCore                          0x27c25581 <redacted> + 368
    16  QuartzCore                          0x27c25243 <redacted> + 590
    17  QuartzCore                          0x27c771cf <redacted> + 762
    18  IOMobileFramebuffer                 0x2dab857b <redacted> + 86
    19  IOKit                               0x2534df29 IODispatchCalloutFromCFMessage + 256
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x2424b0d9 <redacted> + 132
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x2425d3f3 <redacted> + 34
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x2425cb07 <redacted> + 342
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x2425af19 <redacted> + 1688
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x241ae249 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 520
    25  CoreFoundation                      0x241ae035 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 108
    26  GraphicsServices                    0x2d277ad1 GSEventRunModal + 160
    27  UIKit                               0x283c38a9 UIApplicationMain + 144
    28  ProductName                         0x000c16bb main + 202
    29  libdyld.dylib                       0x3635e873 <redacted> + 2
)
```

What might be the problem here? Why `UIKit` decides to update `UILabel` again back to normal which is not the expected behavior?

I suspect Unity's iOS native support class might get involved, but after seeing above I don't think so.
This problem happens to all `UILabel` **only** and **only** for those that have multiple size class set for different font size.

**FYI**: I use Xcode 7.0 (7A220), and Unity 5.2.1f1.